# WPF - FormatException, Не конвертирует Brush

Tags: c#, wpf

Я использую цветовые коды для использования собственных цветов, и для этого мне нужен был ConvertFrom, но вылетает FormatException, когда я создаю экземпляр класса (из которого потом беру поле Color)

Объявляю

```
public class CustomColor
    {
        public Brush Color;

        public CustomColor(string colorCode)
        {
            Color = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(colorCode);
        }
    }
```

Экземплярирую

```
public class Styles
    {
        public static CustomColor Color0 = new CustomColor("000000");
        public static CustomColor Color1 = new CustomColor("f67e7d");
        public static CustomColor Color2 = new CustomColor("ffb997");
    }
```

и ломается прога

пс. может я неправильно понял ошибку, заранее простите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ffb997` -> `#ffb997`

Comment: Чтобы вообще красиво стало, надо свойство `public Brush Color { get; }`, тогда даже биндинги смогут работать. Но я не особо понимаю, зачем вы собираете цвета таким образом, если можно накидать их в ресурсы прямо в XAML.